# Radio Coming Through Speakers In Home

Tags: wiring

I've lived in a mobile home for a long time that has bad wiring. Even the receptacles are mounted bad and I have to tape plugs to the wall for them to stay in.

For years there never was a problem but the last year I have radio stations coming through the speakers I have my computer hooked up to. It's just
speakers, there's no receiver.

It happens 24 hours a day and its annoying. I can't sit here in peace and quiet.

I knocked the plug out of the wall the other day and told my landlord to fix the outlet. He hasn't yet, but can the receptacles or wiring have something to do with the radio coming through?

Comment: Since it is something that did not happen for years and now does, it sounds like a new comm. tower was put in nearby recently, or more antennas added to an existing one nearby. Try the speakers in a neighboring unit or in a car with an inverter to rule out or confirm your outlet and wiring being a problem.

Answer (score 3):

I take it these are powered speakers plugged into the computer?  They usually have very cheap, poorly-shielded little amplifiers in them which are good at demodulating radio and playing it out the speaker.  A mobile phone call nearby will typically also cause a bunch of beeping and "dirtdirtdirt" noises.

If your computer has a three-pin plug but is plugged into an ungrounded outlet or the ground is faulty on that outlet, that is a safety issue and may also contribute to the noise.

If you've got some $2 earbuds, plug those into the PC and see if you get radio noise.  If the earbuds are quiet and produce the PC sounds properly, then you know the problem is probably with the powered speakers.  If the earbuds also play radio, then the fault is either in the computer or its grounding.

Comment: i got a new power strip but im not using it until the outlet is replaced. i have an indoor air conditioner, not a wall or window mounted one that has been going off and the old power strip is old because i have to move it around to get the air back on. so that mite have alot to do with it i honestly never thought of the rca to computer cord but if nothing else ill get a new one ill look at the fusebox

Answer (score 1):

It probably is not the landlord's fault.

If you are dealing with very strong local radio signals, all you can do is sell or throw away any electronics that are manufactured in unshielded plastic boxes, and only buy high quality electronics in shielded metal boxes from stores where you can easily return items that fail in your environment -- and even then, you may need to take extra steps such as applying ferrite RFI suppression chokes to all input and output wires.

(If you are wondering if you can sue the radio station or ask them to replace your devices, you can't.  They have a license to cause this kind of problem, and at least in the USA, the FCC has decided that RFI is typically the product manufacturer's fault and not the radio station's fault).

What you have is a very strong radio signal around devices that aren't designed to reject it.

This problem is called [Radio Frequency Interference](http://www.arrl.org/radio-frequency-interference-rfi).  In the early days of AM radio, people made [crystal radios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_radio) that did not need electricity at all -- consisting of a tuned filter and a non-linear junction supplied by a crystal or, in modern children's kits, a modern diode -- the result was a signal strong enough to hear in sensitive headphones. If the signal is strong enough, you don't need the tuned filter, and such signals may similarly be received unintentionally by cheap unshielded modern electronics.

Ideally computer speakers should be in metal boxes instead of plastic boxes. The metal box acts as a Faraday cage to shield the audio amplifier from undesired radio signals that might otherwise be received by the amplifier circuit. You can put [rfi suppression ferrite beads](http://www.k0bg.com/beads.html) on all input and output leads to the speakers to block the radio signal from travelling down the speaker or power wires, but if the speakers are in plastic boxes that may not help and buying a better model may be more time and cost effective.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are the power supply of your PC or some other component is sensitive to radio interference. It could also be the speakers themselves. It may not be the fault of your property owner (unless the outlets are ungrounded).

Try plugging your speakers into another source, such as a phone or MP3 player.

Comment: ive had an imac since i lived here, theres nothing to it, not even two inches thick and the size of the monitor theres nothing else i got a different one last may, older model but the same ive had the speakers since i moved in over 5 years ago and its never happened until now nothings changed in this room